# RFID Scanner supports Embedded Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce, barcode-scanner, rfid

I have an in-house application deployed in Wince Scanners, built in Embedded Visual C++ (EVC++).

Will this technology supports RFID Scanners also or I need to migrate the application to C# or some other technology ?

Thanks,
Anurag

Comment: Which model(s) of RFID scanners are you targeting?

Comment: Hi Darryn,The RFID Scanners may be MC3190-Z or MC9190-Z

Answer (score 1):

eMbedded Visual C(EVC)++ 4.0 is a development environment for Windows CE 4.x/5.0.
As you are planning (Zebra?) MC3190-Z/MC9190-Z is Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.x, you probably will not be able to use EVC.
As the development environment of the MC3190-Z/MC9190-Z, it will be VisualStudio 2005/2008.
However VisualStudio 2005 is no longer supported.
In addition, the support period of VisualStudio 2008 will end in the spring of 2018.
VisualStudio 2008(as well as 2005?) can be downloaded by contracting VisualStudio subscription.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  To add to this, I think you will need to use the professional version of VS2008 for mobile development.  You will also need the MC9190 Platform SDK (https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/mc9100-sdk.html) as well as the EMDK SDK for .NET that exposes the RFID APIs: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/emdk-for-net.html

Comment: Hi Kunif,  Thanks for the response and sorry for the delay from my end. Looking at the support periods of VS 2005/2008, shall we plan for VS 2010 or any other environment you would like to suggest ?

Comment: I think that it is difficult to use other than VS2005/2008. 
Because, as written by @Darryn Campbell, SDK of the corresponding device is necessary for development, and it seems that it depends on the version number of VisualStudio. 
For further information and consultation, please contact Zebra's support & service.